# Jacobian of a Reservoir Computer - Symbolic Form

Tags: neural-network, derivative

I have a vector valued function: F(**h**) = (1-a)* **h** + a*tanh(W<sub>in</sub> * x + W * **h**)

https://reservoirpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/node.html

a is a constant, x is an external input, W<sub>in</sub> is the input weight vector, and W is a matrix with the coupling strength between vector elements, and h is the vector representing the internal (hidden) states of the network.

The derivative, were this one variable, is dF/dh = a + W * sech<sup>2</sup>(W<sub>in</sub> * x + W * h)

I would like to compute the Jacobian. I am currently computing this numerically, but I would like to check my work against the symbolic solution of the equation.

With the numerical solution, I loop through each vector element, add + and - perturbation (eps = 1e-8), take the difference, and divide by eps.

```
    def numerical_jacobian(x, res, h_t, j_eps):
        n = np.size(h_t,1)
        jac = np.zeros((n,n))
        for i in range(n):
            hf = h_t.copy()
            hb = h_t.copy()
            hf[0][i] = hf[0][i] + j_eps
            hb[0][i] = hb[0][i] - j_eps
            hf_state = res.call(x, from_state = hf, stateful = False)
            hb_state = res.call(x, from_state = hb, stateful = False)
            jaccol = (hf_state - hb_state)/(2*j_eps)
            jac[:,i] = np.transpose(jaccol[0])
        return jac
```

[BTW - I am aware that autograd would be the best solution, as it would be much more efficient. But at the moment, I am using someone else's code and, after starting down that path, it would be quite a bit of work to rework it. They wrote everything as a numpy array (vs Pytorch or tensorflow).]

I have tried refactoring the expression for the derivative, treating all of the h values except for one (each pass through the loop) as a constant.

Using a vector of length 3 as an example.

W * **h** = W11*h1 + W12*h2 + W13*h3 + W21*h1 + W22*h2 + W23*h3 + W31*h1 + W32*h2 + W33*h3

D = W12*h2 + W13*h3 + W22*h2 + W23*h3 + W32*h2 + W33*h3.  # constant for all but index 1

M = W11 + W21 + W31 # constant coefficient on index 1

C = W<sub>in</sub> * x # vector, but a constant

b = (1-a)*(h2 + h3) # constant

-- back to the original expression, but making substitutions

F(**h**) = (1-a)* **h** + a*tanh(W<sub>in</sub> * x + W * **h**)

F(h<sub>1</sub>) = b + (1-a) * h<sub>1</sub> + a * tanh(C + D + M * h<sub>1</sub>)

dF(h<sub>1</sub>) = M * a * sech<sup>2</sup>(C + D + M * h<sub>1</sub>) - a + 1

```
def symbolic_jacobian(W_in, W, x, h_t):
    n = np.size(h_t,1)
    jac = np.zeros((n,n))
    h = np.ndarray.flatten(h_t)

    C = W_in * x  # vector, but a constant

    for i in range(n):
        M = 0.0
        D = 0.0

        # sum just the values in this column of W
        for j in range(n):
            M = M + W[j][i]     # single valued constant

        # sum W*h for all but this column
        for j in range(n):   
            for k in range(n):
                if k != i:
                    D = D + W[j][k] * h[k]  # single valued constant
    
        
        E = C * D                   # n x 1
        G = E + M * h[i]            # n x 1  
        H = np.tanh(G)              # n x 1

        # reminder that sech(Z) = 1 - tanh<sup>2</sup>(Z)
        h_deriv = (a * M * ((1 - (H * H))*(1 - (H * H)))) - a + 1 # n x 1

        jac[:,i] = np.transpose(h_deriv) # 1 x n
    return jac
```

```
The numerical and symbolic jacobians do not match. Here are the differences. 

[[-1.61322219e-02  3.08682911e+00  2.81308279e-04]

 [ 1.54216918e-04  3.10315716e+00  1.98080410e-04]

 [ 2.37444787e-04  3.10230650e+00 -1.61204694e-05]]

Thanks very much!
```